# Как увеличить MySQL тайм-аут с 8 часов до 24?

Tags: mysql

У меня стоит сервер, и мне нужно чтобы его соединение с базами данных висело постоянно. Потому что, есть подозрения, что при сбросе соединения MySQL-ом, куда-то теряется установленная кодировка, и начинаются ошибки запросов. А 24 часа подключения обезопасит от такого варианта событий.

Comment: *мне нужно чтобы его соединение с базами данных висело постоянно.* Вот эта хотелка требует весьма серьёзного обоснования...

Answer (score 0):

Вроде решилось костылем "SET NAMES ...;" при создании подключения. Протестировал с тайм-аутом в 5 сек, работает без ошибок.